# Initialize static array with values

Tags: c++

I have a class which is entirely static. Inside the class is a pointer to a list of integers of variable length. The functions inside the class depend on the first value in the list being initialized to 2 before they are called. Some of the functions are also called very frequently so I don't want to set that value first thing in every function.

Here is an example of the header:

```
class Foo{
public:
  static void f1();
private:
  static int* list;
}
```

and the .cpp file, globally (outside other function calls):

```
int* Foo::list = new int[10];
```

I need to initialize list[0] =2  somehow but that is not allowed in the same location as I have the list initializer.

Comment: _"I have a class which is entirely static."_ Why?

Comment: _"I need to initialize list[0] =2 somehow but that is not allowed in the same location as I have the list initializer."_ So?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Could be a base class with lots of constants. For example shape colours.

Comment: @AndyG: [The initialiser can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86f03f2218f85582). Crucially, the initialiser is not "anybody but `Foo`".

Comment: I hope that `static` is not on your definition in real life, since it is invalid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit edited static out. The class is essentially a math library. I need to access the functions and it doesn't make sense to tie them to an object of type Foo.

Comment: Then `namespace` that shiz ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++ 2011 then write

```
int* Foo::list = new int[10] { 2 };
```

Another way is for example to define a private static function. For example

```
class Foo
{
// ...
private:
    static int *list;
    static int * init() 
    {
        int *p = new int[10];
        p[0] = 2;
        return p;
    }       
};

int* Foo::list = Foo::init();
```